# Creating a custom model builder DXA Java | XPM Issue

Tags: dxa, experience-manager, sdl-tridion, dxa-java, dxa-2.0

I have a requirement similar to this question: [Disable Experience Manager (XPM) DXA 2.0 Java, for specific CT](https://tridion.stackexchange.com/questions/19169/disable-experience-manager-xpm-dxa-2-0-java-for-specific-ct?rq=1)

Rick has mentioned in his answer to create a custom model builder to achieve this. However, I cannot find any online rws docs/tutorials on creating a custom model builder.

Also, once we create a custom model builder, where do we need to register this custom model builder in a JAVA application?

How will this model builder be picked up by dxa framework?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

DXA 2.x allows you to customize Model Building both on CM-side and on CD-side. In this particular case (customizing XPM metadata), you can choose either side, because XPM metadata is generated on CM-side.

Online documentation for customizing/extending DXA in general can be found here: https://docs.rws.com/784837/314608/sdl-digital-experience-accelerator-2-2/customizing-and-extending-------------dxa